# DNSPython ImportError: No module named 'dns.zone'; 'dns' is not a package

Tags: python-3.x

Хочу подключить в файл библиотеку [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/)

Пишу в файле

```
import dns
import dns.zone
```

Но получаю ошибку

> ImportError: No module named 'dns.zone'; 'dns' is not a package

Python версии 3.5.1

Модуль *[dnspython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dnspython/1.12.0)* ставил через pip3

```
pip3 install dnspython
```

Вот этот код выводит список установленных модулей через pip

```
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
  installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
     for i in installed_packages])
  print(installed_packages_list)
```

Выдает он следующее:

```
['dnspython3==1.12.0']
['dnspython3==1.12.0']
```

Вопрос: почему выдает два установленных модуля и почему ругается, когда я делаю import.

Помогите пожалуйста. Никак не получается подключить модуль dnspython в своем проекте.

Comment: А как называется исходный файл? Точно не dns.py?

Comment: Попробуйте переустановить модуль

Comment: @tonal, вы гений, он  у меня назывался dns.py. Спасибо, проблема решена.